Solve a transcendental equation with sympy
I have trouble solving the following simple equation with sympy.
Sympy seems to take way too much time to produce a result.
import sympy as sp
sp.solve(sp.Eq(1000/(sp.exp(log(39) - 1000*k) + 1), 100), k)

The solution is log(39)/1000 - log(3)/500, which can be verified by plugging that into the equation.
What can one do to "help" sympy to solve this equation for k?

I think solve is attempting to solve this as a polynomial equation of degree 1000 in exp(k) which is apparently slow.
You can use solveset instead:
In [16]: eq
Out[16]: 
     1000            
─────────────── = 100
        -1000⋅k      
1 + 39⋅ℯ             

In [17]: solveset(eq, k)
Out[17]: 
⎧n⋅ⅈ⋅π   log(13/3) │      ⎫   ⎧ⅈ⋅(2⋅n⋅π + π)   log(39) │      ⎫
⎨───── + ───────── │ n ∊ ℤ⎬ \ ⎨───────────── + ─────── │ n ∊ ℤ⎬
⎩ 500      1000    │      ⎭   ⎩    1000         1000   │      ⎭

In [18]: solveset(eq, k, Reals)
Out[18]: 
⎧-log(3/13) ⎫
⎨───────────⎬
⎩   1000    ⎭


You can get the single solution from solve by making the 1000 a symbol:
>>> from sympy import *
>>> k=var('k');solve(sp.Eq(1000/(sp.exp(log(39) - Symbol('1000')*k) + 1),100)
[log(13/3)/1000]

Or you can use a symbol that you replace with the 1000 in the solution:
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> solve(sp.Eq(1000/(sp.exp(log(39) - x*k) + 1),100), k, dict=True)
[{k: log(13/3)/x}]
>>> [Dict(i).subs(x,1000) for i in _]
[{k: log(13/3)/1000}]

